# Failed Building to WebGL ( unable to compile firebase )

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have an issue with building the app into WebGL, when I build to android it Works but after I changed to WebGL found a lot of error with no reason, mostly firebase stuff. I can't delete the firebase because it has an important part of my Game, or maybe anyone can tell me alternate ways without using Firebase.

[image: Firebase Error]

when I click on that error nothing error found on my script

[image: one of my script]

can anyone tell me if I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK for Unity doesn't support WebGL builds.

You can use `#define` directives to ignore Firebase in your code (so you don't get "Firebase could not be found" exception). You can read more about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html